# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

I have been trying to solve and find what's wrong with my gradle file. I am trying to build my app but I keep getting these errors.

```
**
```

**E:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk

```
 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10.
     Required by:
         project :
      > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally. However we cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10:
          - gradle70JavadocElements
          - gradle70RuntimeElements
          - gradle70SourcesElements
          - javadocElements
          - runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute
          - sourcesElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'gradle70JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'gradle70RuntimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'gradle70SourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
        The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
          - Variant 'apiElementsWithFixedAttribute' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
          - Variant 'gradle70ApiElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10 declares a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           23.9s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1**
```

**

while this is my android\build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0-alpha09'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:4.3.13'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I just changes the versions based on the suggested version.

Comment: My answer to a similar problem can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73894514/13773254

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use Kotlin 1.7.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73342537/cannot-use-kotlin-1-7-10)