# Cannot use Kotlin 1.7.10

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Kotlin project in IntelliJ IDEA (not targeting Android) that currently compiles fine with Kotlin 1.6.10. When I change to 1.7.10, I get the following errors:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'jwotd'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally. However we cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0:
          - gradle70JavadocElements
          - gradle70RuntimeElements
          - gradle70SourcesElements
          - javadocElements
          - runtimeElements
          - sourcesElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'gradle70JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'gradle70RuntimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'gradle70SourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides sources but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
        The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
          - Variant 'gradle70ApiElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a runtime of a component
```

My top-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

One of my project build.gradle (there are several projects, all similar):

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs "src/java"
    }
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {
    api project(':cjk')
    implementation project(':kokuban')
    implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.beust:klaxon:5.0.1' 
    implementation "com.oracle.database.xml:xmlparserv2:21.1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Open your gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file and modify the gradle version to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
```

Comment: Finally, a solution that works! Kudos!

Answer (score 8):

In my case, Just replace to

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21'
```

From

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10'
```

Comment: works for me as well

Comment: works, but what if I want to use 1.7.10, what should I update or remove?

Answer (score 6):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html

> When configuring your project, check the Kotlin Gradle plugin compatibility with available Gradle versions:

Kotlin 1.7.20 requires **Gradle 6.7.1 as a minimum version.** Kotlin 1.7.10 will do similarly.
Please check your Gradle version.

Answer (score 5):

I had to manually upgrade `gradle`.

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 7.5.1
./gradlew --version
./gradlew build
```

After this, gradlew builds Kotlin 1.7.10 code, and it also builds successfully in IntelliJ IDEA. Interestingly though, the IntelliJ complains about unavailable features (definitely typed T & Any), but it can compile it and it seems to work.

Feels like IntelliJ IDEA CE does not officially support Kotlin 1.7.10 yet?

Comment: Please make sure you're using the Kotlin IDE plugin with 1.7+ compiler (not 1.6). Results of the IDE analysis depend on the version of the IDE plugin, not the Gradle plugin.

Comment: How can I upgrade the plugin? When I "check for updates", the IDE thinks it's up-to-date.

Comment: Ok, so you probably have a 1.7-based IDE plugin. Check the Project structure dialog -> Facets, make sure that the language and API versions for the module are 1.7 as well. In a Gradle project these value should be automatically imported from the corresponding configuration in the build.gradle scripts. If the versions are wrong in the facets, you can try to remove .idea and .gradle directories and reimport the project in IDEA.

Comment: Yes, all modules are set to Kotlin 1.7 already. Interestingly, today the IDEA no longer complains about `T & Any`. Seems like it has fixed itself. If it happens again, I'll try reimporting the project.

Comment: With my configuration and for Kotlin 1.7.20, it didn't work with Gradle 7.5.1. Instead, I had to use Gradle 6.7.1.

Answer (score 1):

Invalidate Caches and Restart resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this in your build and gradle.

> ```
> kotlinOptions {
>     jvmTarget = "1.8"
> }
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem. I also tried wrapping it in `compileKotlin`, or setting `languageVersion = 1.7`. I still get the same error. The error also occurs when I try building it from console with `./gradlew build`, so it's not an IDE-only issue.

Comment: this was not solution 
already added in .gradle file

Answer (score 0):

This is how a freshly generated (by IDEA CE / gradle-7.4.2) `build.gradle` looks like

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.7.10'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

Comment: interesting. so IDEA CE _does_ support kotlin 1.7.10… this is the top-level build.gradle, right? how does the inner project build.gradle look like?