# Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I downloaded an old flutter project from github and opened it in android studio. When I run, it's giving the following error.

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally. However we cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0:
          - gradle70JavadocElements
          - gradle70RuntimeElements
          - gradle70SourcesElements
          - gradle71JavadocElements
          - gradle71RuntimeElements
          - gradle71SourcesElements
          - gradle75JavadocElements
          - gradle75RuntimeElements
          - gradle75SourcesElements
          - gradle76JavadocElements
          - gradle76RuntimeElements
          - gradle76SourcesElements
          - javadocElements
          - runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute
          - sourcesElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'gradle70JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'gradle70RuntimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
```

**app\build.gradle**

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }



    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.learn_quran_app"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/com.android.tools/proguard/coroutines.pro'
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}


dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've been trying to make the suggested changes in similar links [Cannot use Kotlin 1.7.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73342537/cannot-use-kotlin-1-7-10) & [kotlin error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843441/kotlin-error-could-not-find-org-jetbrains-kotlinkotlin-stdlib-jre71-0-7) but nothing's working. please help.

Comment: As the error indicates you need a JRE/JDK 8 for building this project. Your current Java version is most likely a newer version which is not compatible with Java 8.

Comment: So how can I solve it? I tried installing jdk 8 too and then running it, still the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

update gradle like

**android/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
```